# Picking up the information entered by a user in TextFields doesn't work?

Tags: java, frame, textfield

I am writing a little code in which the user sets up fuses for a firework on a Frame with different buttons on it, and then when he presses launch the animation a new window pops up and the firework is drawn on it, with a method called peindre from which I know it works already (I've tested it carefully).

When I compile the class used for this frame, a window with the wanted buttons appear and everything goes well until I press launch the animation, in which case only a black window appears. The first thing peindre does (the code is underneath) is paint the whole window black, and then it launches Threads for each fuse that wait a certain time and then draw the fuses and erase them, this worked when I tested it directly. But here I can't see any of the fuses appear ! I can when I create one myself in the main though, so it's really a problem of my program not getting the information the user types in right.

```
//ATTRIBUTES
    public TextField duree, tpsExplosion, altitude, avancement, puissEtincelles ;
    public double dureed, tpsExplosiond, xf, yf, puissEtincellesd ;
    public boolean bicoloreb ;
    public Choice choixForme, choixCouleur ;
    public String forme ;
    public Color couleur ;
    public Button plus ;
    public Button animation ;
    public Checkbox bicolore ;
    public FenetreAnimeeSansCanvas fenetreAnimee ; 
    public FenetreNouvelleFusee fenetreNouvelleFusee ; 
    int numero = 0 ;
    public String choixFormes, choixCouleurs;
    static final long serialVersionUID=1L;  

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public AnimationSansCanvas() { 
        super("AnimationSansCanvas") ;
        altitude = new TextField("Altitude de l'explosion") ;
        avancement = new TextField("Position de l'explosion sur l'axe des abscisses");
        duree = new TextField("Durée de l'affichage de la fusée") ;
        tpsExplosion = new TextField("Moment de l'explosion (par rapport au début de l'animation)");
        choixForme = new Choice();
        choixForme.add("Choix de la forme :");
        choixForme.add("Étoile");
        choixForme.add("Croix");
        choixForme.add("Point");
        choixCouleur = new Choice();
        choixCouleur.add("Choix de la couleur :");
        choixCouleur.add("Rouge");
        choixCouleur.add("Vert");
        choixCouleur.add("Bleu");
        choixCouleur.add("Rose");
        choixCouleur.add("Jaune");
        choixCouleur.add("Orange");
        puissEtincelles = new TextField("Puissance de 8 du nombre d'étincelles");
        plus = new Button("Ajouter une fusée") ;
        animation = new Button ("Lancer l'animation") ;
        bicolore = new Checkbox("Fusée bicolore (la deuxième moitié sera rouge)", false) ;
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.add(altitude) ;
        this.add(avancement) ;
        this.add(duree);
        this.add(tpsExplosion);
        this.add(choixForme);
        this.add(choixCouleur);
        this.add(puissEtincelles);
        this.add(plus);
        this.add(animation);
        this.add(bicolore);
        altitude.addActionListener(this);
        avancement.addActionListener(this);
        duree.addActionListener(this);
        tpsExplosion.addActionListener(this);
        puissEtincelles.addActionListener(this);
        plus.addActionListener(this);
        animation.addActionListener(this);
        choixCouleur.addItemListener(this);
        choixForme.addItemListener(this);
        bicolore.addItemListener(this);
        addWindowListener(new EcouteurPourFermetureFenetre()); //pour tout arrêter en cas de fermeture de fenêtre
        setResizable(true);

        fenetreAnimee = new FenetreAnimeeSansCanvas() ;
                fenetreAnimee.setVisible(true);
    }

    //METHODES
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        if (evt.getSource() == plus){ 
            numero += 1 ;
            fenetreNouvelleFusee = new FenetreNouvelleFusee() ;
            fenetreNouvelleFusee.numero = numero ;
            fenetreNouvelleFusee.setVisible(true); 
            fenetreAnimee.fusees.add(fenetreNouvelleFusee.fuse) ; 
        }
        if (evt.getSource() == animation){
            numero += 1 ;
            Fusee fuse = new Fusee(numero) ;
            puissEtincellesd =
            Double.valueOf(puissEtincelles.getText());
            tpsExplosiond = Double.valueOf(tpsExplosion.getText());
            dureed = Double.valueOf(duree.getText());
            xf = Double.valueOf(avancement.getText());
            yf = Double.valueOf(altitude.getText());
            fuse.bicolore = bicolore.getState() ;
            fuse.couleur = couleur ;
            fuse.puissEtincelles = (int)puissEtincellesd ;
            fuse.xf = xf ;
            fuse.yf = yf ;
            fuse.forme = forme ;
            fuse.duree = dureed ;
            fuse.tpsDepart = tpsExplosiond ;
            fenetreAnimee.fusees.add(fuse) ; 
            fenetreAnimee.peindre(fenetreAnimee.getGraphics());  
            fenetreAnimee.setVisible(true); 
        }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ivt){  
        if (ivt.getSource()==choixCouleur){
            if (choixCouleur.getSelectedItem()=="Rose"){
                couleur = Color.pink ;
            }
            if (choixCouleur.getSelectedItem()=="Bleu"){
                couleur = Color.blue ;
            }
            if (choixCouleur.getSelectedItem()=="Vert"){
                couleur = Color.green ;
            }
            if (choixCouleur.getSelectedItem()=="Rouge"){
                couleur = Color.red ;
            }
            if (choixCouleur.getSelectedItem()=="Jaune") {
                couleur = Color.yellow ;
            }
            if (choixCouleur.getSelectedItem()=="Orange") {
                couleur = Color.orange ;
            }
        }
    }


    //MAIN
    public static void main(String [] abs){
           AnimationSansCanvas anim = new AnimationSansCanvas();
           anim.setLocation(100, 100);
           anim.setSize(600, 450);
           anim.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I must be doing something wrong in getting the information the user gives but I can't see my mistake ! When I add a fuse in the main myself it draws it fine, it just doesn't seem to get the info that I type into the frame. It would be great if someone could tell me what's wrong with my program :)

And here's the code for fenetreAnimeeSansCanvas, fenetreNouvelleFusee, Etincelle and Fusee ! 
(don't feel like you need to look at it it's just in case you want to compile the whole program)

(in peindre, the threads just count time passing, then draw the fuses and then erase them again when their time is over)

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.* ;
import java.util.concurrent.*;


public class FenetreAnimeeSansCanvas extends Frame {


//ATTRIBUTS
    public LinkedList <Fusee> fusees ;
    int w,h, numEnCours=1, numMax = 1, puissEtincellesMax=1 ;
    double duree = 1 ;
    boolean suspended ;


    //CONSTRUCTEUR
        public FenetreAnimeeSansCanvas() {
            super("FenetreAnimeeSansCanvas") ;
            setSize(1200,700) ;
            setLocation(120,100) ;
            setResizable(true) ;
            w = this.getSize().width ;
            h = this.getSize().height ;
            addWindowListener(new EcouteurPourFermetureFenetre());
            fusees = new LinkedList() ;
        }

        //METHODES
        public void peindre(Graphics gr){       
            gr.setColor(Color.black);
            gr.fillRect(0, 0, w, h); 
            for (Fusee fus : fusees) {
                fus.g = gr ; 
                fus.anim.start();
            }
        }




        //MAIN
        public static void main(String [] abs){
               FenetreAnimeeSansCanvas fen = new FenetreAnimeeSansCanvas() ;
               fen.setVisible(true) ;

               Fusee fus = new Fusee(1) ;
                fus.forme = "point" ;
                fus.tpsDepart = 5 ;
                fus.puissEtincelles = 6 ;
                fus.couleur = Color.orange ;
                fus.duree = 10 ;
                fus.xf = 567 ;
                fus.yf = 590 ;
                fus.active = true ;
                fen.fusees.add(fus) ;        


                   Fusee fus1 = new Fusee(2) ;
                    fus1.forme = "etoile" ;
                    fus1.tpsDepart = 12 ;
                    fus1.puissEtincelles = 12 ;
                    fus1.couleur = Color.pink ;
                    fus1.duree = 20 ;
                    fus1.xf = 1000 ;
                    fus1.yf = 150 ;
                    fus1.active = true ;
                    fen.fusees.add(fus1) ;        


                       Fusee fus2 = new Fusee(3) ;
                        fus2.forme = "croix" ;
                        fus2.bicolore = true ;
                        fus2.tpsDepart = 10 ;
                        fus2.puissEtincelles = 8 ;
                        fus2.couleur = Color.green ;
                        fus2.duree = 32 ;
                        fus2.xf = 276 ;
                        fus2.yf = 290 ;
                        fus2.active = true ;
                        fen.fusees.add(fus2) ;   

                        Fusee fus3 = new Fusee(3) ; 
                        fus3.forme = "point" ;
                        fus3.tpsDepart = 14 ;
                        fus3.bicolore = true ;
                        fus3.puissEtincelles = 12 ;
                        fus3.couleur = Color.blue ;
                        fus3.duree = 20 ;
                        fus3.xf = 850 ;
                        fus3.yf = 370 ;
                        fus3.active = true ;
                        fen.fusees.add(fus3) ;  

               Graphics gr = fen.getGraphics();
               fen.peindre(gr);   
               } 
}

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.* ;

public class FenetreNouvelleFusee extends Frame implements ActionListener, ItemListener{

//ATTRIBUTS 
public TextField duree, tpsExplosion, altitude, avancement, puissEtincelles ;
public double dureed, tpsExplosiond, xf, yf, puissEtincellesd ;
public Choice choixForme, choixCouleur ;
public String forme ;
public Color couleur ;
public Button pret ;
public Checkbox bicolore ;
public int numero ;
public String choixFormes, choixCouleurs;
public Fusee fuse ;
static final long serialVersionUID=1L;  

//CONSTRUCTEUR
public FenetreNouvelleFusee() { 
    super("FenetreNouvelleFusee") ;
    setSize(600,450) ;
    setLocation(150,150) ;
    altitude = new TextField("Altitude de l'explosion") ;
    avancement = new TextField("Position de l'explosion sur l'axe des abscisses");
    duree = new TextField("Durée de l'affichage de la fusée") ;
    tpsExplosion = new TextField("Moment de l'explosion (par rapport au début de l'animation)");
    choixForme = new Choice();
    choixForme.add("Choix de la forme :");
    choixForme.add("Étoile");
    choixForme.add("Croix");
    choixForme.add("Point");
    choixCouleur = new Choice();
    choixCouleur.add("Choix de la couleur :");
    choixCouleur.add("Rouge");
    choixCouleur.add("Vert");
    choixCouleur.add("Bleu");
    choixCouleur.add("Rose");
    choixCouleur.add("Jaune");
    choixCouleur.add("Orange");
    bicolore = new Checkbox("Fusée bicolore (la deuxième moitié sera rouge)", false) ;
    puissEtincelles = new TextField("Puissance de 8 du nombre d'étincelles");
    pret = new Button("Fusée prête !") ;
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    this.add(altitude) ;
    this.add(avancement) ;
    this.add(duree);
    this.add(tpsExplosion);
    this.add(choixForme);
    this.add(choixCouleur);
    this.add(puissEtincelles);
    this.add(pret);
    this.add(bicolore);
    altitude.addActionListener(this);
    avancement.addActionListener(this);
    duree.addActionListener(this);
    tpsExplosion.addActionListener(this);
    puissEtincelles.addActionListener(this);
    pret.addActionListener(this);
    choixCouleur.addItemListener(this);
    choixForme.addItemListener(this);
    bicolore.addItemListener(this);
    addWindowListener(new EcouteurPourFermetureFenetre()); 
    setResizable(true);
}

//METHODES
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        if (evt.getSource() == pret){ 
            numero += 1 ;
            fuse = new Fusee(numero) ;
            puissEtincellesd = Double.valueOf(puissEtincelles.getText());
            tpsExplosiond = Double.valueOf(tpsExplosion.getText());
            dureed = Double.valueOf(duree.getText());
            xf = Double.valueOf(avancement.getText());
            yf = Double.valueOf(altitude.getText());
            fuse.bicolore = bicolore.getState() ;
            fuse.couleur = couleur ;
            fuse.puissEtincelles = (int)puissEtincellesd ;
            fuse.xf = xf ;
            fuse.yf = yf ;
            fuse.forme = forme ;
            fuse.duree = dureed ;
            fuse.tpsDepart = tpsExplosiond ;
            fuse.puissEtincelles = (int)puissEtincellesd ;
            setVisible(false) ; 
        }
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ivt){
        if (ivt.getSource()==choixCouleur){
            if (choixCouleur.getSelectedItem()=="Rose"){
                couleur = Color.pink ;
            }
            if (choixCouleur.getSelectedItem()=="Bleu"){
                couleur = Color.blue ;
            }
            if (choixCouleur.getSelectedItem()=="Vert"){
                couleur = Color.green ;
            }
            if (choixCouleur.getSelectedItem()=="Rouge"){
                couleur = Color.red ;
            }
            if (choixCouleur.getSelectedItem()=="Jaune") {
                couleur = Color.yellow ;
            }
            if (choixCouleur.getSelectedItem()=="Orange") {
                couleur = Color.orange ;
            }
        }
        if (ivt.getSource()==choixForme){
            forme = choixForme.getSelectedItem(); 
        }
    }

    //MAIN
    public static void main(String [] abs){
           FenetreNouvelleFusee fen = new FenetreNouvelleFusee();
           fen.setVisible(true) ;
           } 

}



import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;



public class Etincelle {
//ATTRIBUTS
public Color couleur ;
public double duree, x,y ;
public String forme ;
public BufferedImage image ;
Graphics g ; 
//CONSTRUCTEUR
public Etincelle(double a, double b){
    x=a;
    y=b;
    forme = "croix";
    couleur=Color.red ; 
    image = new BufferedImage(15,15, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); 
    g = image.createGraphics();
}

//METHODES
public void peindreEtincelle(Graphics globalg) {
    g.setColor(couleur);
    if (forme == "croix") {
        g.drawLine(6-5, 6, 6+5, 6);
        g.drawLine(6, 6-5, 6, 6+5); 
    }
    else if (forme == "point"){
        g.fillOval(6, 6, 8, 8);
    }
    else if (forme=="etoile"){
        g.drawLine(6-5, 6, 6+5, 6);
        g.drawLine(6, 6-5, 6, 6+5); 
        g.drawLine(6-5, 6-5, 6+5, 6+5);
        g.drawLine(6-5, 6+5, 6+5, 6-5); 
    }
    globalg.drawImage(image,(int)x,(int)y,null); 
}


//MAIN
public static void main(String[] args) {
     }




}


import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;


public class Fusee extends Canvas implements Runnable {
//ATTRIBUTS
public int num, puissEtincelles, nbEtincelles;
public double xf, yf, duree, tpsDepart ;
public boolean active = true, bicolore = false, suspended = false ;
public String forme ;
public Thread anim ;
public int k = 0 ;
public Color couleur, couleur2 = Color.red ;
public static double DIV = 1%(Math.sqrt(2)) ;
public LinkedList<Etincelle> liste;
public Graphics g;
int w, h ; 
static final long serialVersionUID=1L;


//CONSTRUCTEUR
public Fusee(int numero){   /
    num = numero ;
    active = true ;
    couleur = Color.red ;
    nbEtincelles = 1 + 8^puissEtincelles; 
    anim = new Thread(this) ; 
    liste = new LinkedList<Etincelle>() ; 
    liste.add(new Etincelle(xf,yf));   
    for (int k =1 ; k<=puissEtincelles ;k++){
        liste.add(new Etincelle(xf+10*k,yf));
        liste.add(new Etincelle(xf-10*k,yf));
        liste.add(new Etincelle(xf,yf+10*k));
        liste.add(new Etincelle(xf,yf-5*k));
        liste.add(new Etincelle(xf+10*k*DIV,yf+10*k*DIV));
        liste.add(new Etincelle(xf+10*k*DIV,yf-10*k*DIV));
        liste.add(new Etincelle(xf-10*k*DIV,yf+10*k*DIV));
        liste.add(new Etincelle(xf-10*k*DIV,yf-10*k*DIV));
    }

    w = 1200 ;
    h = 700 ;
}

 //METHODE
public void run(){                  
    while (true){
    if (active == true){
        if (tpsDepart == 0) {
          if (duree>0){ 
             if (bicolore == false) {
                 duree = duree-1 ;
                 peindreFusee(g) ;
                 if (k<puissEtincelles) {
                    k+=1 ;
                    }
             }
             else if (bicolore == true){
                 duree = duree-1 ;
                 peindreFuseeBicolore(g) ;
                 if (k<puissEtincelles) {
                    k+=1 ;
                    }
             }
          }
          else if (duree == 0){
             active = false ;
          }
        }
        else if (tpsDepart >0){
            tpsDepart = tpsDepart - 1 ; 
        }
    }
    else if (active == false){  
        couleur = Color.black ; 
             peindreFuseeFin(g) ;
         }
         else if (bicolore == true){
             couleur2 = Color.black ;
             peindreFuseeBicoloreFin(g) ;
         }
        anim.stop(); 
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(400);
      }
      catch(InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
    }
}






public String toString(){
    String chaine = "Numéro fusée" ;
    chaine += "  " + String.valueOf(num);
    chaine += "  " +String.valueOf(yf);
    chaine += "  " +String.valueOf(xf);
    chaine += "  " +String.valueOf(duree);
    chaine += "  " +String.valueOf(tpsDepart);
    chaine += "  " +String.valueOf(forme);
    chaine += "  " +String.valueOf(couleur);
    chaine += "  " +String.valueOf(puissEtincelles);
    chaine += "  " +String.valueOf(bicolore);
    return chaine ;
}





public void peindreFusee (Graphics g){

    Etincelle etinc0 = new Etincelle(xf,yf) ;  
    etinc0.couleur = couleur ;
    etinc0.forme = forme ;
    etinc0.duree = duree ;
    etinc0.peindreEtincelle(g);
        Etincelle etinc1 = new Etincelle(xf+10*k,yf) ;
        etinc1.couleur = couleur ;
        etinc1.forme = forme ;
        etinc1.duree = duree ;
        etinc1.peindreEtincelle(g);
        Etincelle etinc2 = new Etincelle(xf-10*k,yf) ;
        etinc2.couleur = couleur ;
        etinc2.forme = forme ;
        etinc2.duree = duree ;
        etinc2.peindreEtincelle(g);
        Etincelle etinc3 = new Etincelle(xf,yf+10*k) ;
        etinc3.couleur = couleur ;
        etinc3.forme = forme ;
        etinc3.duree = duree ;
        etinc3.peindreEtincelle(g);
        Etincelle etinc4 = new Etincelle(xf,yf-10*k) ;
        etinc4.couleur = couleur ;
        etinc4.forme = forme ;
        etinc4.duree = duree ;
        etinc4.peindreEtincelle(g);
        Etincelle etinc5 = new Etincelle(xf+10*k*DIV,yf+10*k*DIV) ;
        etinc5.couleur = couleur ;
        etinc5.forme = forme ;
        etinc5.duree = duree ;
        etinc5.peindreEtincelle(g);
        Etincelle etinc6 = new Etincelle(xf+10*k*DIV,yf-10*k*DIV) ;
        etinc6.couleur = couleur ;
        etinc6.forme = forme ;
        etinc6.duree = duree ;
        etinc6.peindreEtincelle(g);
        Etincelle etinc7 = new Etincelle(xf-10*k*DIV,yf+10*k*DIV) ;
        etinc7.couleur = couleur ;
        etinc7.forme = forme ;
        etinc7.duree = duree ;
        etinc7.peindreEtincelle(g);
        Etincelle etinc8 = new Etincelle(xf-10*k*DIV,yf-10*k*DIV) ;
        etinc8.couleur = couleur ;
        etinc8.forme = forme ;
        etinc8.duree = duree ;
        etinc8.peindreEtincelle(g);
    }


public void peindreFuseeBicolore (Graphics g){
        Etincelle etinc0 = new Etincelle(xf,yf) ;   
        etinc0.couleur = couleur ;
        etinc0.forme = forme ;
        etinc0.duree = duree ;
        etinc0.peindreEtincelle(g);
            Etincelle etinc1 = new Etincelle(xf+10*k,yf) ;
            etinc1.couleur = couleur ;
            etinc1.forme = forme ;
            etinc1.duree = duree ;
            etinc1.peindreEtincelle(g);
            Etincelle etinc2 = new Etincelle(xf-10*k,yf) ;
            etinc2.couleur = couleur2 ;
            etinc2.forme = forme ;
            etinc2.duree = duree ;
            etinc2.peindreEtincelle(g);
            Etincelle etinc3 = new Etincelle(xf,yf+10*k) ;
            etinc3.couleur = couleur ;
            etinc3.forme = forme ;
            etinc3.duree = duree ;
            etinc3.peindreEtincelle(g);
            Etincelle etinc4 = new Etincelle(xf,yf-10*k) ;
            etinc4.couleur = couleur2 ;
            etinc4.forme = forme ;
            etinc4.duree = duree ;
            etinc4.peindreEtincelle(g);
            Etincelle etinc5 = new Etincelle(xf+10*k*DIV,yf+10*k*DIV) ;
            etinc5.couleur = couleur ;
            etinc5.forme = forme ;
            etinc5.duree = duree ;
            etinc5.peindreEtincelle(g);
            Etincelle etinc6 = new Etincelle(xf+10*k*DIV,yf-10*k*DIV) ;
            etinc6.couleur = couleur ;
            etinc6.forme = forme ;
            etinc6.duree = duree ;
            etinc6.peindreEtincelle(g);
            Etincelle etinc7 = new Etincelle(xf-10*k*DIV,yf+10*k*DIV) ;
            etinc7.couleur = couleur2 ;
            etinc7.forme = forme ;
            etinc7.duree = duree ;
            etinc7.peindreEtincelle(g);
            Etincelle etinc8 = new Etincelle(xf-10*k*DIV,yf-10*k*DIV) ;
            etinc8.couleur = couleur2 ;
            etinc8.forme = forme ;
            etinc8.duree = duree ;
            etinc8.peindreEtincelle(g);

}


public void peindreFuseeFin(Graphics g){
    Etincelle etinc0 = new Etincelle(xf,yf) ;   
    etinc0.couleur = couleur ;
    etinc0.forme = forme ;
    etinc0.duree = duree ;
    etinc0.peindreEtincelle(g);
    for (int k=1 ; k<=puissEtincelles +3 ; k++){
        Etincelle etinc1 = new Etincelle(xf+10*k,yf) ;
        etinc1.couleur = couleur ;
        etinc1.forme = forme ;
        etinc1.duree = duree ;
        etinc1.peindreEtincelle(g);
        Etincelle etinc2 = new Etincelle(xf-10*k,yf) ;
        etinc2.couleur = couleur ;
        etinc2.forme = forme ;
        etinc2.duree = duree ;
        etinc2.peindreEtincelle(g);
        Etincelle etinc3 = new Etincelle(xf,yf+10*k) ;
        etinc3.couleur = couleur ;
        etinc3.forme = forme ;
        etinc3.duree = duree ;
        etinc3.peindreEtincelle(g);
        Etincelle etinc4 = new Etincelle(xf,yf-10*k) ;
        etinc4.couleur = couleur ;
        etinc4.forme = forme ;
        etinc4.duree = duree ;
        etinc4.peindreEtincelle(g);
        Etincelle etinc5 = new Etincelle(xf+10*k*DIV,yf+10*k*DIV) ;
        etinc5.couleur = couleur ;
        etinc5.forme = forme ;
        etinc5.duree = duree ;
        etinc5.peindreEtincelle(g);
        Etincelle etinc6 = new Etincelle(xf+10*k*DIV,yf-10*k*DIV) ;
        etinc6.couleur = couleur ;
        etinc6.forme = forme ;
        etinc6.duree = duree ;
        etinc6.peindreEtincelle(g);
        Etincelle etinc7 = new Etincelle(xf-10*k*DIV,yf+10*k*DIV) ;
        etinc7.couleur = couleur ;
        etinc7.forme = forme ;
        etinc7.duree = duree ;
        etinc7.peindreEtincelle(g);
        Etincelle etinc8 = new Etincelle(xf-10*k*DIV,yf-10*k*DIV) ;
        etinc8.couleur = couleur ;
        etinc8.forme = forme ;
        etinc8.duree = duree ;
        etinc8.peindreEtincelle(g);
    }
}



public void peindreFuseeBicoloreFin(Graphics g){
    Etincelle etinc0 = new Etincelle(xf,yf) ;   
    etinc0.couleur = couleur ;
    etinc0.forme = forme ;
    etinc0.duree = duree ;
    etinc0.peindreEtincelle(g);
    for (int k=1 ; k<=puissEtincelles +3; k++){
        Etincelle etinc1 = new Etincelle(xf+10*k,yf) ;
        etinc1.couleur = couleur ;
        etinc1.forme = forme ;
        etinc1.duree = duree ;
        etinc1.peindreEtincelle(g);
        Etincelle etinc2 = new Etincelle(xf-10*k,yf) ;
        etinc2.couleur = couleur2 ;
        etinc2.forme = forme ;
        etinc2.duree = duree ;
        etinc2.peindreEtincelle(g);
        Etincelle etinc3 = new Etincelle(xf,yf+10*k) ;
        etinc3.couleur = couleur ;
        etinc3.forme = forme ;
        etinc3.duree = duree ;
        etinc3.peindreEtincelle(g);
        Etincelle etinc4 = new Etincelle(xf,yf-10*k) ;
        etinc4.couleur = couleur2 ;
        etinc4.forme = forme ;
        etinc4.duree = duree ;
        etinc4.peindreEtincelle(g);
        Etincelle etinc5 = new Etincelle(xf+10*k*DIV,yf+10*k*DIV) ;etinc1.couleur = couleur ;
        etinc5.couleur = couleur ;
        etinc5.forme = forme ;
        etinc5.duree = duree ;
        etinc5.peindreEtincelle(g);
        Etincelle etinc6 = new Etincelle(xf+10*k*DIV,yf-10*k*DIV) ;
        etinc6.couleur = couleur2 ;
        etinc6.forme = forme ;
        etinc6.duree = duree ;
        etinc6.peindreEtincelle(g);
        Etincelle etinc7 = new Etincelle(xf-10*k*DIV,yf+10*k*DIV) ;
        etinc7.couleur = couleur2 ;
        etinc7.forme = forme ;
        etinc7.duree = duree ;
        etinc7.peindreEtincelle(g);
        Etincelle etinc8 = new Etincelle(xf-10*k*DIV,yf-10*k*DIV) ;
        etinc8.couleur = couleur2 ;
        etinc8.forme = forme ;
        etinc8.duree = duree ;
        etinc8.peindreEtincelle(g);
}
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't override the **boolean action()** method because of which the program works only once, with the text with which the **TextField**s are initialised. Add this code after the main method:

```
@Override
public boolean action(Event EV, Object obj){
    repaint(); //this statement is missing in your code
    return true;
}
```

This should work. I tested it's absense in an applet and I had the same error as you did.

---

**EDIT**

Since your program doesn't have a paint() method (I should have noticed it) and the button doesn't seem to function, try implementing the following code in your program to handle the event triggered by the button when clicked: (*Consider the Button Animation is labelled as "Start Animation"*)

```
public boolean handleEvent(Event EV){
    if(EV.target instanceof Button){
        if(EV.arg.equals("Start Animation"))
            //do what you want to do when button is clicked
    }
    return super.handleEvent(EV);
}
```

Maybe you missed this or a similar part.

Comment: Thanks for your help @ProgyadeepMoulik ! However my program doesn't have a paint method (I know it's better to have one and I tried to add one, but the only solution I found after lots of time spent on it was not to use it), which makes me wonder exactly what this action is supposed to repaint ? Maybe I can find an equivalent with the methods I've written until now ?

Comment: As for your comment I was worried it might be too long (because if you want to compile FenetreAnimeeSansCanvas you actually need four other classes) but you're probably right I'll do it next time :)

Comment: Please tell me where you handle the event triggered by the **animation** button. There should be method handling this event and I can't see it. (Maybe there is there but I can't understand).

Comment: When launch the animation is clicked, a new Fusee fuse is constructed with all the characteristics entered by the user in the TextFields, then this fuse is added to the fusees list from fenetreAnimee, which is then painted by peindre and set visible. I know the painting part works since when I add a fuse manually to that list in the main I can see it, but the fuses entered by the user are just not registered... Thanks for your help @ProgyadeepMoulik I really don't know what's wrong ^^

Comment: Sadly it still doesn't work @ProgyadeepMoulik, and I don't think it's the animation button because that button launches the peindre (=paint) method which is definitely executed when I add a fuse manually to the list ! It's just that the fuses set up by the user are not added or the TextFields aren't read properly and I still can't figure out why... But thanks for your help anyways :)

Comment: Umm I'm sorry about that. I tried with whatever I knew. If it still hasn't been solved then the only way would be to carefully go through your code entirely and also use a debugger. :)